# Make p-tree node use whole width of parent div

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-tree

I'm trying to insert a progress bar inside a p-tree node. The problem is that the progressbar only extends as far as the label of the node.

Using "width: 100%" doesn't work.

How can I extend the node width to use the whole width of its parent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a html of what you're trying to do?